# Is there a Python ORM framework for interacting with data via XML-RPC?

Tags: python, django, orm, xml-rpc

I am working on a webapp that interacts with data via XML-RPC rather than with a direct connection to a database.  I can execute SQL queries via an XML-RPC methods.

I would like to interact with the data in an ORM framework fashion that has lazy/eager fetching, etc., although I can't seem to figure out how that would be possible with Python or even Django's libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [XML Models](http://djangorestmodel.sourceforge.net).  It's REST rather than XML-RPC, but much of it is probably reusable.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own database backend. Take a look at [existing backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/) for how to do this.